# container name="header.panel" Magento2

Tags: magento-2.0, luma-theme

`container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel"` - (welcome message area) - on the far left I want to call a cms block. I tried the widget but that block appears below the the welcome message. I want it the same line.

I am using Magento 2 Luma, how do I add add a custom CMS block there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have to apply CSS styling to the `widget-block` in order to get it to `float:left`.